# Rails installation runtime error

Tags: rails, ruby-on-rails

hi guys I'm trying to install rails using ubntu desktop 14.04

my ruby version is `ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]` i install it with rvm

my gem version `gem -v 2.5.0`

when i try to run the gem install rails the system give my the follow error 
[error description](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13211502/)

if some could guide me will be really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

sorry about this i was missing the libgmp-dev library 
 `sudo apt-get install libgmp-dev`

Comment: **Attention LQ reviewers: OP answering his own question!** (voted "Looks OK" on answer and VTC on Q)